# Div doesn't follow the pointer

Tags: html, pointers

I have a div that is supposed to follow the pointer, but it stays very far from the pointer right now, though it follows it.

I've tried some different codes, both written by me, suggested on here, or found online, but nothing helped.

Right now the one that works best is this..

```
var currentMousePos = { x: -1, y: -1 };
    $(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    currentMousePos.x = event.pageX;
    currentMousePos.y = event.pageY;
    $(".hidden-img").css('top', currentMousePos.y);
    $(".hidden-img").css('left', currentMousePos.x);
});
```

I've also tried this http://jsfiddle.net/BfLAh/1/ but it doesn't work as in the fiddle

It follows the pointer but it's very far from the top left of the pointer.

Comment: The 'left' follows correctly, but the 'top' is not aligned - currently the div stays way below the pointer.
Any leads?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the position of image's top left corner and mouse pointer, then jsut set negative `margin-top`, and `margin-left` for you image like below:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

 $("body").mousemove(function (e) {

  $("#image").animate({
   left: e.pageX,
   top: e.pageY
  }, 1);
 });
});
```

```css
body {
 overflow:hidden;
 position:absolute;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 background:#efefef;
}

#image {
 height:50px;
 width:50px;
 margin-top:-10px;
 margin-left:-10px;
 position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <img id="image"></img>
</div>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/fp50ngj1/) is its link to check it online in fiddle.

**UPDATE**

If your only reason for detecting mouse position is to show and hide the content of list items, then you don't need to detect mouse position manually, you can do it using `jQuery` with ease. First add this selector to your `CSS` file:

```
li.list-item div {
  display: none;
}
```

And then you can show child of each `.small-item` using `mouseover` and `children` like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.list-item').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).children('.small-title').show();
    }).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).children('.small-title').hide();
    });
})
```

We can get rid of this because as you mentioned in your comment you just want to fix the child state.

```
.mouseout(function() {
    $(this).children('.small-title').hide();
})
```

Comment: I had to put top: -50%; but I am afraid that it isn't the right practice as it might get screwed on different screens?
What's the matter?

Comment: top on `#image` selector? if so, it'll change the top position of image at start time. If you're curious about cross browser support [here](http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/mouse-position/) is a good comparison between different ways of getting cursor position.

Comment: It won't position next to where the cursor is, but to the screen..
Also on that page there's nothing for the pointer. Consider that I have different <li> that get hovered so the position of the hidden div inside the li element is always relative to the pointer

Comment: I think we aren't understanding each other :P tho I appreciate your help a lot!
Here is a link of my current webpage http://mircofragomena.com/WIP as you see each project has a title and to each title there is a hidden div, that appears and follows the mouse. Right now it shows just the hidden div of the first project, but every project has its own hidden div..now the only 2 rows have a different image but anyway the problem is the same. The mouse position is important to keep the div attached to the mouse..

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to go with this code and make it work, at least the positioning

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".list-item").mousemove(function(e) {
        var offset = $(".list-item").offset();
        $("#hoverDisplay").animate({
            left: e.pageX - offset.left,
            top: e.pageY - offset.top
        }, 1);
    });
});
```

Now the only problem that stays is, I have 20+ "li" items that have to get hovered and show their own hidden div.
Here is the code of just 2 "li" elements.

```
<li class="list-item" style="background-color: #03C0A4;">
                    <div class="small-title" style="color:#E07354">nevaly</div>
                    <a href="a-project-called/nevaly/index.html" style="color:#E07354" class="project-title" onmouseenter=toggleHiddenDisplay("hoverDisplay") onmouseout=toggleHiddenDisplay("hoverDisplay")>Connecting brands and influencers - no limits.</a>
                    <div class="hidden-img" id="hoverDisplay" style="display:none;">
                        <img src='a-project-called/nevaly/thumb.gif'>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-item" style="background-color: #f8e975;">
                    <div class="small-title" style="color:#e32e1d">Kulturhavn</div>
                    <a href="a-project-called/kulturhavn/index.html" style="color:#e32e1d" class="project-title" onmouseenter=toggleHiddenDisplay("hoverDisplay") onmouseout=toggleHiddenDisplay("hoverDisplay")>Ahoy! From the cultural harbour of Copenaghen.</a>
                    <div class="hidden-img" id="hoverDisplay" style="display:none;">
                        <img src='a-project-called/kulturhavn/thumb.gif'>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

Now when I hover just the first hidden div content gets shown.

How can I take the hoverDisplay of the hovered "li" element using the JS that I wrote (thanks to you also guys!)?!

Thanks

Comment: Is that the only reason for detecting mouse position?

Comment: I mean, the hidden div needs to be shown when the parent list-item gets hovered - then, the position now is already fixed